# Using a Winforms App to Configure a Windows Service

Tags: winforms, windows-services

I have a single project made up of a Winform and a Windows Service.  When installed, they both exist in the same, common folder, c:\program files\

I would like for the Winform to be able to set settings such as connection strings, passwords, logfile paths, etc. in a common xml file that both applications share.  i will handle all of the encryption and decryption so that is not my issue.

The issue seems to be that when the application is installed, the Winform is unable to update the  file and I get an access denied error although I am a COMPLETE domain admin with absolute rights over the desktop.

The question is, how does one go about allowing a Winform to define a common connection string between both the Winform application and the Windows service it wishes to configure?

I do NOT want to rely on the machine.config and want my own XML file that will hold all of the configuration options.  There must be something simple I'm missing, a simple solution?

Comment: not an answer but a work around - have you considered using registry instead of xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The registry has caused nothing but headaches in the past since Microsoft seems to have moved to the application.config route and have really started to lock down the registry.  Add to that the entire WOW6432 branching and it has become more difficult to use.

My current solution, which seems to be working well, it to have the following function to point to the same location whether called from the service or the Winform as long as both have the same company name and product name.  I then place my own XML config file in that location and all is well in the world.

```
' **********************************************************************************************************
' Returns Commong Data Folder
' If folder does not exist, it attempts to create it
' **********************************************************************************************************
Public Function GetCommonDataFolder(ByRef ErrorMessage As String) As String
    Dim Result As String = ""

    Result = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & "\" & My.Application.Info.CompanyName & "\" & My.Application.Info.ProductName

    Try
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage = "An exception occurred creating directory: " & Result & ": " & ex.Message
    End Try

    Return Result
End Function
```